# Box Responsiva invadindo outros elementos da Pagina

Tags: html, css

Olá, eu estou desenvolvendo um site e encontrei o seguinte problema:
Usei uma Box que achei legal nesse [Vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZA9kwht8n9Q&list=PL5e68lK9hEzeJyVEeZICW8oJLmH3l3iw6&index=2&t=0s), porém, quando a box começava a ficar responsiva ela cobria os elementos da pagina toda. Então utilizei de "@medias" e dei "padding-top" para ir ajustando as imagens de acordo com a resolução de cada aparelho, mas quando eu crio qualquer conteúdo embaixo dessa box, esses conteúdos sobrepõe a box ou a box sobrepões esses conteúdos.
Queria ajuda para que a Box em questão não invadisse outros conteúdos e que eu não precisasse dar "padding-top" a cada resolução, grato.

```css
/*Cursos*/
.BoxGeral
{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  width: 1000;
  height: 0;
  display: flex;
}
.BoxGeral .BoxCursos
{
  background: black;
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #ccc;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.BoxGeral .BoxCursos:hover
{
  transform: scale(1.1);
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
.BoxGeral .BoxCursos .ImagensCaixa
{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.BoxGeral .BoxCursos:nth-child(odd) .ImagensCaixa
{
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.BoxGeral .BoxCursos .ImagensCaixa img
{
  width: 100%;
}
.BoxGeral .BoxCursos .Detalhes
{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #262626;
}
.BoxGeral .BoxCursos:nth-child(even) .Detalhes
{
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.BoxGeral .BoxCursos:nth-child(1) .Detalhes
{
  background: #6adc5e;
}
.BoxGeral .BoxCursos:nth-child(2) .Detalhes
{
  background: #345a30;
}
.BoxGeral .BoxCursos:nth-child(3) .Detalhes
{
  background: #6adc5e;
}
.BoxGeral .BoxCursos:nth-child(4) .Detalhes
{
  background: #345a30;
}
.BoxGeral .BoxCursos:nth-child(5) .Detalhes
{
  background: #6adc5e;
}
.BoxGeral .BoxCursos:nth-child(6) .Detalhes
{
  background: #345a30;
}
.BoxGeral .BoxCursos .Detalhes .Conteudo
{
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% + 16px);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.25s;
}
.BoxGeral .BoxCursos:hover .Detalhes .Conteudo
{
  top: calc(50%);
}
.BoxGeral .BoxCursos .Detalhes .Conteudo .fas
{
  font-size: 80px;
  color: #fff;

}
.BoxGeral .BoxCursos .Detalhes .Conteudo h3
{
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  color: #fff;
}
.BoxGeral .BoxCursos .Detalhes .Conteudo a
{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.5s;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transform: scale(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #eee;
  background-position: right;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.BoxGeral .BoxCursos:hover .Detalhes .Conteudo a
{
    transform: scale(1);
}
.BoxGeral .BoxCursos .Detalhes .Conteudo a:hover
{
  background: #fff;
  color: #262626;
}
@media(max-width: 1000px)
{
  .BoxGeral
  {
    padding-top: 80%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .BoxGeral .BoxCursos
  {
    height: 250px;
  }
    .BoxGeral .BoxCursos .ImagensCaixa
  {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media(max-width: 768px)
{
  .BoxGeral
  {
    display: initial;
    padding-top: 10%;
  }
  .BoxGeral .BoxCursos .ImagensCaixa
  {
    display: none;
  }
  .Eventos
  {
    padding-top: 40%;
  }
}
@media(max-width: 480px)
{
  .BoxGeral
  {
    padding-top: 130%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transform: translate(0);
  }
  .Eventos
  {
    padding-top: 250%;
  }
}
@media(max-width: 375px)
{
  .BoxGeral
  {
    padding-top: 160%;
  }
  .Eventos
  {
    padding-top: 300%;
  }
}
@media(max-width: 320px)
{
  .BoxGeral
  {
    padding-top: 200%;
  }
  .Eventos
  {
    padding-top: 360%;
  }
}

/*Cursos*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--BoxDeCursos-->
                <div class="BoxGeral container">
                    <div class="BoxCursos">
                      <div class="ImagensCaixa">
                        <img src="img/BoxCursos/dev.jpg">
                      </div>
                      <div class="Detalhes">
                      <div class="Conteudo">
                          <i class="fas fa-laptop-code"></i>
                          <h3>Análise e Desenvolvimento de Sistemas</h3>
                          <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dev">Sobre</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  <div class="BoxCursos">
                      <div class="ImagensCaixa">
                        <img src="img/BoxCursos/adm.jpg">
                      </div>
                      <div class="Detalhes">
                        <div class="Conteudo">
                          <i class="fas fa-book"></i>
                          <h3>Administração</h3>
                          <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#adm">Sobre</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  <div class="BoxCursos">
                      <div class="ImagensCaixa">
                        <img src="img/BoxCursos/mec.jpg">
                      </div>
                      <div class="Detalhes">
                        <div class="Conteudo">
                          <i class="fas fa-cog"></i>
                          <h3>Mecânica Industrial</h3>
                          <a href="#">Sobre</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="BoxCursos">
                      <div class="ImagensCaixa">
                        <img src="img/BoxCursos/nut.jpg">
                      </div>
                      <div class="Detalhes">
                        <div class="Conteudo">
                          <i class="fas fa-apple-alt"></i>
                          <h3>Nutrição e Dietética</h3>
                          <a href="#">Sobre</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="BoxCursos">
                      <div class="ImagensCaixa">
                        <img src="img/BoxCursos/ser.jpg">
                      </div>
                      <div class="Detalhes">
                        <div class="Conteudo">
                          <i class="fas fa-gavel"></i>
                          <h3>Serviços Jurídicos</h3>
                          <a href="#">Sobre</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="BoxCursos">
                      <div class="ImagensCaixa">
                        <img src="img/BoxCursos/coz.jpg">
                      </div>
                      <div class="Detalhes">
                        <div class="Conteudo">
                          <i class="fas fa-carrot"></i>
                          <h3>Cozinha</h3>
                          <a href="#">Sobre</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
             <div>
             <h1>Qualquer Coisa</h1>
             </div>
        <!--BoxDeCursos-->
```

Comment: Amigo clique no link de Editar ao final da sua pergunta e edite colocando seu CSS, só com esse trecho de HTML não da para te responder com precisão

Comment: Por favor coloque seu CSS também.

Comment: Opa, desculpem. Eu acabei de acrescentar o CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na div `.BoxGeral` vc colocou um tanto de propriedade desnecessárias como position:absolute etc

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Vc pode ver que funciona agora removendo essas propriedade, agora o conteúdo que vem depois não fica mais encoberto.** Coloca tb em Tela Cheia para ver a responsividade.

```css
  /*Cursos*/
  .BoxGeral
{
  /* position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  width: 1000;
  height: 0; */
  display: flex;
}
.BoxGeral .BoxCursos
{
  background: black;
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #ccc;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.BoxGeral .BoxCursos:hover
{
  transform: scale(1.1);
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
.BoxGeral .BoxCursos .ImagensCaixa
{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.BoxGeral .BoxCursos:nth-child(odd) .ImagensCaixa
{
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.BoxGeral .BoxCursos .ImagensCaixa img
{
  width: 100%;
}
.BoxGeral .BoxCursos .Detalhes
{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #262626;
}
.BoxGeral .BoxCursos:nth-child(even) .Detalhes
{
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.BoxGeral .BoxCursos:nth-child(1) .Detalhes
{
  background: #6adc5e;
}
.BoxGeral .BoxCursos:nth-child(2) .Detalhes
{
  background: #345a30;
}
.BoxGeral .BoxCursos:nth-child(3) .Detalhes
{
  background: #6adc5e;
}
.BoxGeral .BoxCursos:nth-child(4) .Detalhes
{
  background: #345a30;
}
.BoxGeral .BoxCursos:nth-child(5) .Detalhes
{
  background: #6adc5e;
}
.BoxGeral .BoxCursos:nth-child(6) .Detalhes
{
  background: #345a30;
}
.BoxGeral .BoxCursos .Detalhes .Conteudo
{
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% + 16px);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.25s;
}
.BoxGeral .BoxCursos:hover .Detalhes .Conteudo
{
  top: calc(50%);
}
.BoxGeral .BoxCursos .Detalhes .Conteudo .fas
{
  font-size: 80px;
  color: #fff;

}
.BoxGeral .BoxCursos .Detalhes .Conteudo h3
{
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  color: #fff;
}
.BoxGeral .BoxCursos .Detalhes .Conteudo a
{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.5s;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transform: scale(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #eee;
  background-position: right;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.BoxGeral .BoxCursos:hover .Detalhes .Conteudo a
{
    transform: scale(1);
}
.BoxGeral .BoxCursos .Detalhes .Conteudo a:hover
{
  background: #fff;
  color: #262626;
}
@media(max-width: 1000px)
{
  .BoxGeral
  {
    padding-top: 80%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .BoxGeral .BoxCursos
  {
    height: 250px;
  }
    .BoxGeral .BoxCursos .ImagensCaixa
  {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media(max-width: 768px)
{
  .BoxGeral
  {
    display: initial;
    padding-top: 10%;
  }
  .BoxGeral .BoxCursos .ImagensCaixa
  {
    display: none;
  }
  .Eventos
  {
    padding-top: 40%;
  }
}
@media(max-width: 480px)
{
  .BoxGeral
  {
    padding-top: 130%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transform: translate(0);
  }
  .Eventos
  {
    padding-top: 250%;
  }
}
@media(max-width: 375px)
{
  .BoxGeral
  {
    padding-top: 160%;
  }
  .Eventos
  {
    padding-top: 300%;
  }
}
@media(max-width: 320px)
{
  .BoxGeral
  {
    padding-top: 200%;
  }
  .Eventos
  {
    padding-top: 360%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--BoxDeCursos-->
                <div class="BoxGeral container">
                    <div class="BoxCursos">
                      <div class="ImagensCaixa">
                        <img src="img/BoxCursos/dev.jpg">
                      </div>
                      <div class="Detalhes">
                      <div class="Conteudo">
                          <i class="fas fa-laptop-code"></i>
                          <h3>Análise e Desenvolvimento de Sistemas</h3>
                          <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dev">Sobre</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  <div class="BoxCursos">
                      <div class="ImagensCaixa">
                        <img src="img/BoxCursos/adm.jpg">
                      </div>
                      <div class="Detalhes">
                        <div class="Conteudo">
                          <i class="fas fa-book"></i>
                          <h3>Administração</h3>
                          <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#adm">Sobre</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  <div class="BoxCursos">
                      <div class="ImagensCaixa">
                        <img src="img/BoxCursos/mec.jpg">
                      </div>
                      <div class="Detalhes">
                        <div class="Conteudo">
                          <i class="fas fa-cog"></i>
                          <h3>Mecânica Industrial</h3>
                          <a href="#">Sobre</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="BoxCursos">
                      <div class="ImagensCaixa">
                        <img src="img/BoxCursos/nut.jpg">
                      </div>
                      <div class="Detalhes">
                        <div class="Conteudo">
                          <i class="fas fa-apple-alt"></i>
                          <h3>Nutrição e Dietética</h3>
                          <a href="#">Sobre</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="BoxCursos">
                      <div class="ImagensCaixa">
                        <img src="img/BoxCursos/ser.jpg">
                      </div>
                      <div class="Detalhes">
                        <div class="Conteudo">
                          <i class="fas fa-gavel"></i>
                          <h3>Serviços Jurídicos</h3>
                          <a href="#">Sobre</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="BoxCursos">
                      <div class="ImagensCaixa">
                        <img src="img/BoxCursos/coz.jpg">
                      </div>
                      <div class="Detalhes">
                        <div class="Conteudo">
                          <i class="fas fa-carrot"></i>
                          <h3>Cozinha</h3>
                          <a href="#">Sobre</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
             <div>
             <h1>Qualquer Coisa</h1>
             </div>
        <!--BoxDeCursos-->
        Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse quidem deserunt assumenda veniam adipisci officiis, iste, odio harum architecto animi quod quam repellat nam sequi dolor? Sapiente dolore consectetur corrupti, maxime tempora id ad fugiat possimus totam, sequi nam omnis quam deserunt exercitationem quia, beatae cumque suscipit alias saepe sed atque unde maiores. Tempora accusantium ipsum deleniti assumenda. Facere cumque dolorum consequatur velit blanditiis doloribus tempore ullam quasi minus. Veritatis error ullam molestias obcaecati aliquam quasi illum suscipit odio, recusandae adipisci perspiciatis commodi. Recusandae, voluptatum vitae! Natus, quibusdam architecto deleniti quos, repudiandae libero possimus qui debitis, pariatur voluptates aliquam? Quo enim consectetur hic quae labore, possimus necessitatibus, commodi est repudiandae tempora explicabo quasi eum illo! Error, impedit architecto. Aperiam explicabo nam eos magni fugit ducimus non provident, ea ratione perspiciatis a rem esse aliquam vel dolores. Non placeat consectetur doloremque. Nam minima nemo necessitatibus dolores, veniam harum incidunt quis nobis sequi ullam tempora omnis sint sit modi obcaecati eaque molestiae neque perferendis accusamus exercitationem deserunt rem? Ex velit iste deserunt omnis quae temporibus earum excepturi corrupti eum quos consequuntur inventore voluptas veritatis adipisci quod illo aliquam facere tempore illum rem voluptatum, id odio. Modi doloribus ipsum consequuntur enim quae similique corrupti, optio reiciendis non. Dolorum at ab, natus sed ad error commodi culpa ratione perspiciatis, qui, praesentium est quidem pariatur doloribus dolores totam fuga fugit cum perferendis consequatur non exercitationem ipsa. Repudiandae nemo sunt natus soluta vel odio iusto minima magni dicta doloremque recusandae iure excepturi quia, quos molestiae voluptate nam voluptates consequatur, deserunt fugiat? Harum sed ex aperiam excepturi voluptas possimus numquam optio veritatis impedit maiores ab alias, nemo similique corporis? Quia laboriosam cumque culpa fuga adipisci molestiae aperiam laudantium corporis dolor reiciendis eum perferendis officia, sunt rerum nulla, doloremque vitae! Aut dicta autem assumenda temporibus aliquid commodi obcaecati.
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou direitinho!

Comment: Fico feliz de ter ajudado